# node-sqlite: Cannot Read Property of Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am using the node-sqlite3 to create a REST API for garden-based data collected through an Arduino. I can get basic queries to run fine such as getting all of the data in the database. I'm currently trying to get data using the specific date and have this code setup in my database handler:

```
exports.getSoilByDate = (date, callback) => {
    'use strict';
    db.serialize(function() {
        db.each("SELECT * FROM GARDEN WHERE TIME LIKE '%${date}%';", function(err, row) {
            console.log(row.TIME + ": " + row.SOIL_MOISTURE);
        });
    });
};
```

I'm aware there's no callback currently and I plan on adding that once I stop getting errors. My issue is that I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'TIME' of undefined" at the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging it,

1. add console.log(err) in the callback
2. verify if the column name is "TIME" or "time"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Turned out there wasn't any matches so the `row` returned was undefined. Short answer: best to check for that scenario!

```
if( typeof row !== 'undefined' ) {
    /* got data */
} else {
    /* no data returned */
}
```